# How can I add a specific email recipient to my sharekit item?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, sharekit

So, I'm using sharekit to share some text.  I need to be able to send the email to a pre-defined recipient.  How can I set the mail recipient to the sharekit item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharekit has now implemented this. You can use the example below.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Your title" contentType:SHKURLContentTypeUndefined];

NSArray *recipientArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mail@example.com",nil];
[item setMailToRecipients:recipientArray];

[SHKMail shareItem:item];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
[ShareKit](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/281)

**UPDATE: Sharekit has an update that takes care of this now. See the newly accepted answer.**