# How do i add 'recipient' /'To' field while composing email using sharekit plugin for phonegap?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sharekit

I am using sharekit plugin for phonegap in my application. This plugin allows me to set the body and subject of the email . However it does not have an option to set the 'to' /recipient field. I do not know Objective C. Can you please help me achieve this functionality by giving me a guide on what i need to add/change in which files.

Here is a link to the plugin i am using

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ShareKitPlugin

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a response in this question :

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/7648354/1272540](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637500/how-can-i-add-a-specific-email-recipient-to-my-sharekit-item)

So in ShareKitPlugin.m add in :

```
- (void)shareToMail:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    [SHK setRootViewController:self.viewController];

    SHKItem *item;

    NSString *subject = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *body = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];

    item = [SHKItem text:body];
    item.title = subject;

    // **start of added code
    NSString *recipient = [arguments objectAtIndex:3]; 
    [item setCustomValue:recipient forKey:@"toField"];
    // **end of added code

    [SHKMail shareItem:item];

}
```

and this in SHKMail.m :

```
[mailController setSubject:self.item.title];
[mailController setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];

// **start of added code
NSString *recipient = [self.item customValueForKey:@"toField"];
NSLog(@"recipient: %@", recipient);
if (recipient != nil) {
    NSArray *recipients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:recipient, nil];
    [mailController setToRecipients:recipients];
    [recipient release];
    [recipients release];
}
// **end of added code

[[SHK currentHelper] showViewController:mailController];
```

and in ShareKitPlugin.js :

```
ShareKitPlugin.prototype.shareToMail = function( subject, message , recipient)
{
    if(typeof recipient === undefined){
    recipient = '';
    }

    cordova.exec(null, null, "ShareKitPlugin", "shareToMail", [subject, message , recipient] );

};
```

this code come from gitHub : https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/281

Comment: I am not able to compile as i am getting an error on the first line of the new code in shkmail.m i.e 'NSString *recipient = [item customValueForKey:@"toField"];' . The error i am getting is "use of undeclared identifier 'item' "

Comment: I tried that . I was able to get to composer to load with a email address in the to field. However if i send or exit out of the mail the app gets paused and and jumps to xcode . Also the places where i am not putting a recipient the app pauses and in the console it says terminating app due to uncaught exception . And i see something like 'unrecognised selector sent to instance' . I dont know objective C so i dunno why this is happening

Comment: This is what i see in the console when i try to compose a email without a recipient
Pcg[79795:c07] recipient: <null>
2013-05-23 16:10:24.912 pcg[79795:c07] -[NSNull mf_isLegalCommentedEmailAddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x909678
2013-05-23 16:10:24.912 pcg[79795:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull mf_isLegalCommentedEmailAddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x909678'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x7d8012 0x2fc6e7e...etc)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: ok I have edited the code inside ShareKitPlugin.js to always send a string to shareToMail method

Comment: When i send an email with a recipient which opens perfectly it pauses and this line is highlightes in thread 1 objc_msgsend `0x2fd809b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi` and a green arrow says "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x20c4c6b2)"

Comment: for the second error i don't know where it occurs do you try in the simulator?  EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you try to acces to a released object.I can't help you more without code

Comment: ok thanks. Do u think adding self.item instead of item has something to do with it? . I know u cant say much without the code but still

Comment: I think there is a problem with the MailComposerDelegate he is called each times went you tap cancel or send button. but i have never use share kit so i can't tell you more. If you want send me a exemple project i can take a look